# Determining if a set of points are inside or outside a square

Tags: c++

I have two of these:

```
bool isPointOnShape(int a, int b)
{

}

bool isPointInShape(int a, int b)
{

}
```

Say I have a square, first point (bottom left corner) is x,y (0,0) second point (top left) is (0,2), third is (2,2) and fourth is (0,2).

The Points on shape would be (0,1) (1,2) (2,1) (1,0) and Points in shape is (1,1)

How do I find out the points on shape / in shape and return a true value so that I can store it somewhere?

Comment: Are your functions inside some sort of `Shape` class? Where do you store bottom left and top right corners?

Comment: What shape in particular? What have you tried apart for a square?

Comment: the x,y will be 1,2..N only? it won't be 1.1?

Comment: Is your rectangle always conveniently aligned with the cartesian axes? BTW this is not a C++ question, unless you have some C++ solution with which you encountered problems, in which case you should show it.

Comment: Yes it is in a rectangle class. I store my points using x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll offer a general solution for any shape that can be divided in straight segments.

So, as you may have guessed, I'll start by consider your "shape" as a list of segments that completes a loop. Or simply put a circular list of points that represents a loop, for example, your square would be this list of points:

```
0, 0
0, 2
2, 2
2, 0
```

Note that we consider that there are segments from each point to the next and that the final point connects to the first. Also, we require that no consecutive points are equal, nor the first and last. If there are any, those must be removed before proceeding.

---

Now, for each segment we can determinate the bounding box. For example given this segment:

```
a = (0, 2)
b = (2, 2)
```

Then the range of values in x is [0, 2] and in y is [2, 2] and that is your bounding box for that segment.

The next thing you need is the director vector of the line of the segment. To get that, first calculate the length of the segment:

```
length = sqrt((a.x - b.x)*(a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y)*(a.y - b.y))
```

And then:

```
director.x = (a.x - b.x)/length
director.y = (a.y - b.y)/length
```

Note 1: when then length is 0, then you have an invalid segment. That's why we don't want repeated points.

Note 2: Using the director vector instead of using the equation of the line will make things easier.

---

Now, given a point p, you can determinate if that point is in a segment (if it is one of the points in the list). For the rest of cases we start by looking if it is inside of the axis aligned bounding box. This is done simply by checking the range:

```
if
(
    (p.x >= box.left && p.x <= box.right) &&
    (p.y >= box.top && p.y <= box.bottom) // with origin at the top-left corner
)
{
     //It is inside of the bounding box
}
```

And if it is, then we calculate the distance from the point to the line, if it is 
0 then it is on the line. Now, because of floating point arithmetics, you could test if the distance is less or equal to epsilon, where epsilon is a very small number.

We use this formula:

```
distance vector = (a - p) - ((a - p) · director) * director
distance = the norm of distance vector
```

Where "·" denotes a dot product and "*" denotes an scalar product.

All that rests is to iterate over the segments, for each one calculate the distance and if for anyone the distance is less than epsilon then the point is "on the shape".

---

Ok, but what about "in the shape"?

Well, with a little help of a trick from topology we can determinate if a point is inside or not. This is the same algorithm Windows would use to fill a polygon or polyline (such as deciding what is inside a selected area with free hand in Microsoft Paint).

It goes like this:

> Count the number of segments you have to cross to get to the point from outside. If the number is pair, then it is outside, if it is odd then inside.

You can choose from what direction to reach the point. I choose left.

Once more, you are going to iterate over the segments. For each one we need to decide if it is at the vertical range. For that use the bounding box:

```
if ((p.y >= box.top && p.y <= box.bottom))
{
     //In the vertical range
}
```

Now, determinate if the segment is at left, or right:

```
if (p.x < box.left)
{
     //The segment is at the left
}
else if (p.x > box.right)
{
     //The segment is at the right
}
else
{
     //The segment is close, need further calculation
}
```

In the case that the segment is close we need to calculate the vector distance to that segment and check it's direction.

The vector distance? Well, we already have it, we are taking its norm to determinate the distance. Now, instead of taking the norm, verify the sign of the x coordinate. If it is less than 0, it is right, if it is more than 0 then it is left. If it is 0... it means that the segment is horizontal (because the distance vector is always perpendicular to the segment), you can skip that segment*.

*: In fact, if the segment is horizontal and it is in vertical range, it means that it is at the segment. Are segments "in shape" or not?

Now, you need to count the number of segments at the left, and if it odd, the point is inside the shape. It is out otherwise. This can also be done with the segments that are up, or right, or below. I just picked left.

---

For large shapes where iterating over all the segments is expensive, you can store the segments in some space partitioning data structure. That is beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: This comment is old, but by lords if this isn't an awesome explanation of what was asked; You, sir, should have more votes. kudos.

Answer (score 4):

If I suppose you have a `Rectangle` class and that this class has members `bottomLeft` and `topRight`, you can write something like this:

```
bool Rectangle::isPointOnShape(int x, int y) {
    if (x == bottomLeft.x || x == topRight.x)
        if (y > bottomLeft.y && y < topRight.y)
            return true;

    if (y == bottomLeft.y || y == topRight.y)
        if (x > bottomLeft.x && x < topRight.x)
            return true;
}

bool Rectangle::isPointInShape(int x, int y) {
    bool inX = false;
    bool inY = false;
    if (x > bottomLeft.x && x < topRight.x)
        inX = true;

    if (y > bottomLeft.y && y < topRight.y)
        inY = true;

    return (inX && inY);
}
```

If your shape is not a rectangle, this functions will be different of course.

Comment: I think this is a much better answer, so I removed mine, but it should be noted that this only works for orthogonal rectangles.

Comment: @mux Of course. I think that would be implicit from the existence of the `bottomLeft` and `topRight` members for someone reading the answer though

Comment: will it be the same for square? so when i return inX and inY, how do i Know what is the value of it ?

Comment: @RusydiRusydii The value of what? A square *is* a rectangle, so yes, this works with a square.

Comment: By the way, my values of rectangle are stored x1, x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4. x1,y1 will be bottom left. x2,y2 is top left, so on.. how do I know what value it is then returning true? Do i input that in main() or do a for loop myself?

Comment: @RusydiRusydii It depends on the **input** for your functions. You give a point to your function and then your function returns `true` or `false`. You have to store the points yourself.

Comment: @alestanis I do not have to compare topleft and bottom right?

Comment: @RusydiRusydii You mean to see if bottomLeft is really under topRight? That should be done when you construct your rectangle. In the constructor, you should check that the data you are given is *correct*. In this case *correct* would mean having bottomLeft under and to the left of topRight.